# Maxima - using square brackets in variable names

Tags: maxima

In Maxima, I'd like to numerically solve a system of differential equations in an arbitrary number of variables  `x[1]` ... `x[n]`, using the `rk` function.  I use square brackets in the variable name so that I can index the variables in a for loop.  Here is an example call to `rk` when n = 2:

```
rk([derivativeOfX[1],-2*x[1]+x[2],derivativeOfX[2],x[1]-2*x[2]], [X[1],derivativeOfX[1],X[2],derivativeOfX[2]], [1,1,2,0], [t,0,10,0.1])
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
define: in definition of f_rk_4, found bad argument X[1]
```

If I manually replace `X[1]` with `x1` and `X[2]` with `x2`, the error goes away:

```
rk([derivativeOfX1,-2*x1+x2,derivativeOfX2,x1-2*x2], [x1,derivativeOfX1,x2,derivativeOfX2], [1,1,2,0], [t,0,10,0.1]);
```

It seems that `rk` doesn't like the square brackets in the variable names, but I need them in order to index the variables in a for loop.  What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to have two sets of variables. In the loop you use x[1] and x[2]. Before your rk(...) expression, set x1 equal to x[1] and x2 equal to x[2]. Call rk. Then store x1 in x[1] and x2 in x[2].

Note that you can generate variable names using concat. For example concat('x, 1) will produce the symbol x1.

Comment: And how would I set x1 = x[1] and x2 = x[2] in a loop?  I would still need to index the variables x1 and x2.

Comment: You can generate the variables using concat. The expression   concat('x, 1) gives x1 as result.

Comment: Alright, that's the key piece!  Thanks!  (Just "concat" that comment to your answer and I'll accept it).

Comment: I have added it to the answer.